# Saving image as geotiff (or png)

Tags: metpy

I'm using metpy and siphon to pull down and display radar data. Ideally, I'd like to save only the radar layer for display in, say, LeafletJS.

GDAL appears to offer a solution using gdal_translate:

```
gdal_translate -of PNG -ot Byte -b 1 -scale 10 100 1 255 mygribfile.grib2 out.png
```

Though, if I'm already creating the data layer via the metpy and cartopy libraries, I'm assuming there is a means of taking just the radar layer only, including associated colortables, and saving it as an image in a geo-referenced way so that I can include it as a layer elsewhere. (I don't think matplotlib.pyplot.savefig() will maintain the geographic information.)

Is there a place someone may be able to point me to some example code that could achieve these means? My googling (thus far) has come up empty.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing in matplotlib or metpy do handle this natively. Your best bet is likely to try to use [rasterio](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html) to create the geotiff, which will allow you to specify the geolocation information. You should be able to hand rasterio a numpy array corresponding to the rendered figure, as is done in [this example](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/misc/agg_buffer_to_array.html).

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, DopplerShift. Indeed, I was able to pass a numpy array to rasterio. Unfortunately, when writing out the grid using rasterio, a value error is thrown saying the source shape is inconsistent with the given indexes. I'm unfamiliar enough with rasterio (and creating geo-referenced images) and that may be out of your purview here, but I greatly appreciate the initial direction.